# How to shutdown OpenOffice from my Java Uno application?

Tags: java, openoffice.org, uno

I have Java Uno application which runs on server and performs automated text extraction from documents. I want to shutdown OpenOffice from my application before exiting.  How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using `XDesktop.terminate()`

http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/XDesktop.html

But this will only work (as far as I know) if you started OpenOffice locally.

Comment: XDesktop xDesktop = XDesktop)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDesktop.class, oDesktop);xDesktop.terminate();
  xDesktop = null;